# Container instance network

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am having troubles to connect one ECS container instance(**www, python**) to another container instance (**redis**).

I am getting an `"connecting to 0.0.0.0:6379. Connection refused" error from the www container`.

Both instances are running on the same host and were created using two task definitions each containing one docker image.

Both use Bridge networking mode. Each task is executed by means of a service.

I also did setup service discovery for both services.

**Things I did do and try:**

- Assure that Redis is bound to `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`
- Added port mappings for `www (80)` and `redis` container `(6379)`
- ssh'ed into the `ec2` instance to assure port mappings are ok.  I can telnet to both port `80` and `6379`
- connected to the `www` instance and tested by means of the python console if `0.0.0.0:6379` was available.
  It wasn't the case.   I also tried with the docker(redis) IP address  `172.17.0.3` without luck.  I also tried using the .local service discovery name of the `redis` container without luck.   The service discovery name did not resolve
- resolving the service discovery name from the ec2 container (using dig): `that did work but returned a 10.0.* address`

I am a bit out of option why this is the case.  Obviously things do work on a local development machine.

Update 10/5: I changed container networking to type "**host"** which appears to be working.  Still not understanding why **"bridge"** won't work.